# Rank of the product of two full rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-rank

I have searched for the above topic and found some results, but the answer I am looking for is not found anywhere. Here is my question:

> Given $A_{m \times n}$ matrix with rank $m$, and $B_{n \times p}$ matrix with rank $p$, where $n > p \geq m$. I know that 
>   $$
>   \operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq 
>   \min\left(\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\right)
> $$
>   What I want to know is if this expression holds for equality. I.e is this expression
>   $$
>   \operatorname{rank}(AB) = 
>   \min\left(\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\right) = m
> $$
>   correct? If yes, how can it be proved?

Comment: What have you tried yourself to prove it? Have you tried to find matrices $A$ and $B$ that serve as a counterexample?

Comment: I did create Matrix A and B and find the rank of the Product, it gives me the smaller of rank(A) and rank(B). which means rank(AB) = min(rank(A),rank(B)). Now what i don't know is weather this is true in general, as what i saw in general is the inequality, but don't know if the equality hold to.

Answer (score 2):

(This is a reply to an earlier version of the question with $rank(A)=n$, $rank(B)=p$).

Yes, it holds. The assuptions imply $m\geq n\geq p$ and so you can find a submatrix $A'$ of $A$ that contains $n$ rows of $A$ and hence has size $n\times n$ and is regular. The columns of $B$ are independent and so are the columns of $A'B$. So indeed, 
$$\mathrm{rank} AB=\mathrm{rank} A'B=p=\min\{n,p\}.$$

But as Rupsa pointed out, if the matrices $A,B$ have smaller then the full column rank, then equality doesn't hold in general, such as in $(1,0){0\choose 1}=(0)$.

Comment: Thank Peter, look great, but my assumption is $n > p \geq m$, not as you mentioned above.

Comment: Ah, I see. But then all is clear, as the counter-example above applies to your situation ($2>1\geq 1$).

Answer (score 1):

if we take A and B be 2 non-zero matrices s.t AB= zero matrix   then rank A,rank B >0 but rank of AB = 0 so rank AB is not equal to min{rank A, rank B}

Comment: It seems to me that in the question, $A$ should have rank $n$ and $B$ rank $p$...

Comment: Hi Peter Franek, i am sorry for the confusion in my initial post post. The rank of A should be m, not n and the rank of B is p. Also n > p >= m.